# Excel VBA subscript out of range

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to take a string from each cell split it into the array and then decide how many points to add then add them and display them. However I keep coming up with a subscript out of range error I thought it had something to do with the split statement so I revised it several times and still didn't get any where. I also then thought maybe it wasn't the split and maybe there was nothing in that cell but with the (ElseIf array = "" Then) should have taken care of that. Here's my code:

```
Sub pointsAdd()

'Init Variables
Dim pointArray() As String
Dim j As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim points As Integer

'Make sure the correct sheet is selected
Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate

'Add Points Up
For j = 2 To 100
  Cells(j, 1).Select
  If ActiveCell.Value = "" Then
    j = 100
  Else
    For i = 3 To 22
      Cells(j, i).Select
      pointArray = Split(ActiveCell.Value, ".")

'The next line is where the debugger says the script is out of range
      If pointArray(0) = "Tardy" Then     
        points = 0.5
      ElseIf pointArray(0) = "Failure To Complete Shift" Then
        points = 0.5
      ElseIf pointArray(0) = "Failure To Complete At Least Half Shift" Then
        points = 0.5
      ElseIf pointArray(0) = "Absence" Then
        points = 1
      ElseIf pointArray(0) = "Late Call Off" Then
        points = 2
      ElseIf pointArray(0) = "No Call/No Show" Then
        points = 4
      ElseIf pointArray(0) = "" Then
        i = i + 1
      Else
        MsgBox "Somthing is wrong in Module 1 Points Adding"
      End If

      'Add points to points cell
      Cells(j, 2).Select
      points = points + ActiveCell.Value
      ActiveCell.Value = points
    Next i
  End If
Next j

End Sub
```

Also the format of the string that should be in the cell is "Occurrence.Description.Person.mm/dd/yyyy".

Comment: At what line do you get the subscript out of range error? Click on Debug button when you get that error, the line causing the error will be highlighted in your code.

Comment: But you could also have a blank cell in your i loop?

Comment: Are any of the cells in columns `C:V` empty?  If so, you will get a subscript error when you try to access `pointArray(0)`

Comment: yes that's why I have the else if statement checking for that.

Comment: Lol ok so I was checking the array if the cell was empty or not. I should check that before splitting the string in the cell, and just check the cell itself.

Comment: P.S. Setting the maximum number of substrings into which the input string should be split to -1 in the split statement is redundant, since the default value of this optional parameter is -1.

Comment: yes I know I was messing around with it seeing if that statement was the cause of my problem. I will remove the -1 now.

Comment: Your lines which say `ElseIf pointArray(0) = "" Then` `i = i + 1` will be causing you problems as well.  If a cell contains (for example) `.abcd.Dakota Miller.11/08/2016` then the points added to column B will be the points applicable to the column to the left of that value, and the points applicable to the column to the right of that value will be being ignored.  (It is almost **always** a bad idea to modify the value of a loop counter.)

Comment: Ok I see what you are saying. So it would be like a double jump then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting a subscript out of range error whenever your inner for loop gets an empty cell. The following code is a working version of your code above:

```
Sub pointsAdd()

'Init Variables
Dim pointArray() As String
Dim j As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim points As Integer

'Make sure the correct sheet is selected
Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate

'Add Points Up
For j = 2 To 100

    Cells(j, 1).Select

    If ActiveCell.Value = "" Then
        j = 100
    Else
        For i = 3 To 22

            Cells(j, i).Select

            Dim Val As String
            Val = ActiveCell.Value

            ' Check if cell value is not empty
            If (Val <> "") Then
                pointArray = Split(ActiveCell.Value, ".", -1)

                'The next line is where the debugger says the script is out of range
                If pointArray(0) = "Tardy" Then
                    points = 0.5
                    ElseIf pointArray(0) = "Failure To Complete Shift" Then
                    points = 0.5
                    ElseIf pointArray(0) = "Failure To Complete At Least Half Shift" Then
                    points = 0.5
                    ElseIf pointArray(0) = "Absence" Then
                    points = 1
                    ElseIf pointArray(0) = "Late Call Off" Then
                    points = 2
                    ElseIf pointArray(0) = "No Call/No Show" Then
                    points = 4
                    ElseIf pointArray(0) = "" Then
                    i = i + 1
                    Else
                    ' MsgBox "Somthing is wrong in Module 1 Points Adding"

                End If

                'Add points to points cell
                Cells(j, 2).Select
                points = points + ActiveCell.Value
                ActiveCell.Value = points

            Else

                ' A cell was found empty
                i = 23
            End If


        Next i

    End If
Next j

End Sub
```

Note: It stops to look further when it finds any empty cell in a row. It continues to the next row in that case.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You could try this approach, which includes a little tidying up by removing select statements.

```
Sub pointsAdd()

'Init Variables
Dim pointArray() As String
Dim j As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim points As Integer

'Make sure the correct sheet is selected
Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate

'Add Points Up
For j = 2 To 100
    If Cells(j, 1).Value = "" Then
        exit for
    Else
        For i = 3 To 22
            pointArray = Split(Cells(j, i).Value, ".", -1)

            'The next line is where the debugger says the script is out of range
            If UBound(pointArray) > -1 Then
                If pointArray(0) = "Tardy" Then
                    points = 0.5
                ElseIf pointArray(0) = "Failure To Complete Shift" Then
                    points = 0.5
                ElseIf pointArray(0) = "Failure To Complete At Least Half Shift" Then
                    points = 0.5
                ElseIf pointArray(0) = "Absence" Then
                    points = 1
                ElseIf pointArray(0) = "Late Call Off" Then
                    points = 2
                ElseIf pointArray(0) = "No Call/No Show" Then
                    points = 4
                ElseIf pointArray(0) = "" Then
                    i = i + 1
                Else
                    MsgBox "Somthing is wrong in Module 1 Points Adding"
                End If
            End If
            'Add points to points cell
            points = points + Cells(j, 2).Value
            Cells(j, 2).Value = points
        Next i
    End If
Next j

End Sub
```